# Are NOSQL database usefull for million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, cassandra, nosql

I have a table with more than 500 million rows and around 30 columns.

I need to do select by different columns.

I am just using SQL Server but the performance is not so good, can any NOSQL database help me?

Comment: You’ll have to try. With this information nobody can say anything else. It’s not about the row count. It’s about the data, usage, etc.

Comment: Maintaining performance on a database that size requires optimization - indexes, tuning, etc. all need to be considered. Moving to a NoSQL DB won't magically fix your scalability problems - it will likely make them worse.

Answer (score 3):

500 million rows is not a bad number for SQL database, but I believe it is something with your search query which you need to optimise.

Index all columns properly which you are using in where clause, 
Check your caching property of database server,
If there are joins in table add proper PK-FK pair of references, if PK is not possible add indexes on both tables with particular column you are using in joins.
Check your join criteria that also can be optimised.

If you are facing a problem with SQL database may same problem you will have on NOSQL Database only advantage you get is the distributions of your data and metadata across multiple servers or nodes.

Please reply with your table structure and query so that I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me anything can help. but also indexing the right columns in your database can help or querying the correct way.
Typically Nosql can help you when you need to do a lot of read operations and the database does not to be normalized.

However if your data is highly relational a nosql might not be the solution for you.